# Mastering Math - Grade school- to College-level?

Tags: self-learning, learning, online-resources

I'm having difficulty with my math, fractions and up. I used to understand it all, but it's been so long since I've touched the book (I finished it a couple of months ago, picked it up to review everything), I seem to have forgotten it.

The explanations inside of the individual chapters do no good. They never helped me, and I always resorted to having my older brother helping (who is now away at college), and I can't find any resources online that help at all.

Are there any online tutorials / guides that can help me relearn all this fully, all the way from the basics, up to college level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) has hundreds of maths videos and practice questions.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I upvoted picakhu's answer and it's probably better than mine.  But, this might be helpful still.  Not online, but maybe the [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/index.php?mode=books) would be helpful.  It is what I am going to use for my children, possibly.  There are 8 books starting at algebra and going through calculus.  And, the emphasis is on learning problem solving.  The books are not that expensive and you can buy a full solutions manual for each one, which is also not expensive.

Comment: Actually, AoPS has a ton of online videos corresponding to several of their courses in addition to other valuable resources. They also offer online courses. They are adding elementary school curricula as well.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed w/ Khan Academy, but there are videos out there that teach you essential Calculus topics in less than several minutes.